# SharePoint 2010 Current Navigation subsite not showing parent items

Tags: navigation, site-settings

I have a site structure as such:

```
[site collection]
    -sub 1
    ----sub sub 1
    --------page 1
    --------page 2
    ----sub sub 2
    --------page 1
    --------page 2
    -sub 2
    ----page 1
    ----page 2
```

On all the sub sites, and sub-sub sites I have "Display the same navigation items as the parent site" selected as well as "Show subsites" and "Show pages" checked.

I was expecting that all sites would render the first two levels of navigation (as limited by StaticDisplayLevels), however when on the sub 1 page for example, it renders as if it is the root, not displaying it's sibling sub 2, nor the site collection root.

This has worked fine in other scenarios, so my only guess is that since sub 1 has a sub site (sub sub 2), that it 'resets' itself as a new root. Baffling.

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out something needed to propogate or some timer needed to end... woke up the next morning and it all was back to making sense.